# How can I call a function from an existing View Controller class?

Tags: ios, swift, class, oop, uiviewcontroller

I'm still an early stage Swift developer. I'm trying to create a feature where I click a button on a screen, then I get prompted by the iPhone to allow location, and when I click allow, I am automatically navigated to another screen.

So far I've done the following things:

- created a seperate class ("User") where all the location functions are handled
- Setup a button on the first view controller and the appropiate IBAction that calls the location prompt function from "User"
- Added storyboard IDs for the first and second view controller
- Created a function ("changeScreen") in the first view controller class that performs the navigation to another view
- Setup a listener in the "User" class for when user has clicked allow location, which then calls the "changeScreen" function

I think there's another way to do this (call some sort of completion handler) and I toyed around with that for 1-2 hours and nothing worked. So far this solution has almost completely worked but I get the following error:

> Warning: Attempt to present ____ on _____ whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Here's the code in my "User" class

```
class User: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func getLocation(){

    // For use in foreground
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    //locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    println("hello location")


}

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status:CLAuthorizationStatus){

        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            firstView!.showSecondScreen() // this is where I call the other      class's function

        }
    }
  }
```

Here's the code in my First View controller class

```
var firstView: FirstView? = nil

class FirstView: UIViewController {

var newUser = User()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    firstView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstView") as? FirstView

// here i take the first view controller class and store it into a public variable

}

@IBAction func allowLocationBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    newUser.getLocation()  // this is the first button clicked

}

func showSecondScreen(){

    let secondScreen = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondScreen") as! SecondScreen

    self.presentViewController(secondScreen, animated: true, completion:   nil  )

}
```

Ps. I know I can combine all the code into one class, and it could all work like that. But I want to do it the "proper" way, have different functionalities in different classes.

Comment: How you are displaying FirstView in window?

Comment: Hey Amit, I'm displaying FirstView on the storyboard, just a normal View Controller object and I linked it to "FirstView" class. Does that answer your question?

Comment: - you need to set `first = self` not instantiate a new viewcontroller

Comment: Is FirstView is the root view for the window object? the error saying that you are presenting SecondScreen from FirstView VC, but FirstView is not in the window.

Answer (score 1):

- try to set `first = self` , dont instantiate a new view-controller
- if using storyboard, better to use segues to display another screen

Though the correct thing here would be to have a `UserDelegate` Protocol

`protocol UserDelegate { 
      func displayOtherScreen( )
}`

then in `User` add `var delegate: UserDelegate?`
and in the `locationManager` function instead of calling 
`firstView!.showSecondScreen` call
`delegate?.displayOtherScreen( )`

Then make FirstView adopt the UserDelegate Protocol

```
class FirstView: UIViewController, UserDelegate {
var newUser = User()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    newUser.delegate = self
    ...
    }
    ...
    ...
func displayOtherScreen( ) {
    showSecondSceen( ) 
    }
```

Now there is no need for the first variable..

Comment: You are literally so awesome. This was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Just implemented this and it works smoothly. Thanks Azzaknight!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the situation you are trying handle multiple MVC's. Your second Screen by itself should be a different View and should have its own Model View Controller. That way you are not breaking the rules of MVC architecture. Your `ShowSecondScreen()` function should be controlled by a `SecondViewController`.

Once you have this multiple MVC's defined you can wire them up.
There are some ways to do this - `UISplitViewController, UITabViewController, UINavigationViewController`. In your case, `UINavigationViewController` seems best option. You can add Navigation Controller to wireup MVC's using `Editor -> Embed` on your `class FirstView`. That would make `FirstView controller` as your rootViewController.

Then add a `segue` from your button on the FirstView to your controller for the SecondScreen i.e `SecondViewController`

```
class FirstView: UIViewController {
    override func prepareForSegue(..) {
        if let secondControllerObject = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            if let identifier = segue.identifier {
                 switch identifier {
                       case "<your_buttons_identifier_string" : secondControllerObject .callToSecondScreen() 
/* Now will move the Second View to the top of the MVC stack and you 
will be also able to go back to first view as you have a 
Navigation Controller hooked up.*/
/* callToSecondScreen - should be a controller object displaying the
 controlling and displaying contents in the second screen's view. 
Data for second screen's view will come from its Model */

        }
```

Comment: Thanks dude this is great. However I don't want the view to change when a normal button is clicked, actually when the "Allow" button from the iPhone's "Will you allow location?" prompt. How can I check for this button click? Or how can I fire this segue from the User class?